# How to dynamically change the style in vue single page component for templating

Tags: vue.js, white-labelling

I want to create a SPA with the white labeling capability and I am wondering if there is a way for me to dynamically change the styles tag inside a single page VueJS component?

I think I can manage the template dynamically by using something like

```
<div v-if="condition"></div>
```

But is there similar scheme available for styles ?

Can it be done without using Server Side Rendering?

Comment: I think I found my answer: Multiple <style> tags are supported in a single *.vue file. So that solves the issue.

Comment: It may not if there are too many. May be SSR is the way to go in this case.

Comment: Can you explain how multiple <style> tags helps you in this case?